# Rails printing ruby script when using AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cgi

I am trying to load the output of a ruby file using AJAX into the view. Rails however keeps on printing the ruby file rather than its output. Is there anything I have done wrong? I tried similar code in python and it worked just fine.

This is my view in rail:

```
<script>
    function loadText(input) {
        var xmlhttp;
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("myDiv").getElementByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        /* Open the URL to send the request to */
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "/signup.rb?type="+input, true);
        /* Send the request */
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
    <div id="myDiv"><h1>Let AJAX change this text!</h1></div>
    <button type="button" onclick="loadText('hello')">Say Hello</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="loadText('noHello')">Say something else</button>
```

And in the /public folder I have signup.rb, which is shown below:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'cgi'
cgi = CGI.new
if(cgi['type'] == "hello") 
    puts "Content-Type: text/html"
    puts "Hello"
else
    puts "Content-Type: text/html"
    puts "Goodbye"
end
```

After clicking one of the buttons on my view, the code of this file is loaded into my view rather the output of this file. Is there anyway I can get the output of this file to be loaded in?

Comment: well your file actually has no return value at all. Also the reason you are seeing the file itself is because you are `GET`(ting) it. All this says is retrieve the file. What you need to do is create a Controller to handle this and `GET` the controller action which should respond accordingly. Please note the return value from puts is `nil`.

Comment: I created a controller with an action called respondToLoadText. I put the contents of the signup.rb in there (excluding the require 'cgi'), and routed it appropriately. Then I changed this line: xmlhttp.open("GET", "/signup.rb?type="+input, true); to this: xmlhttp.open("GET", "/SignUp?type="+input, true);

Comment: Now it doesn't do anything, in the ruby console I get:  Parameters: {"type"=>"hello"}
(offline mode: enter name=value pairs on standard input)

Comment: Finally got it working, in my controller I used the following code and it worked:    type = params[:type]
   if(type == "hello")
    render :text => "Hello"
   else
    render :text => "Bye sir"
   end